# JNI - Code behaves abnormally after CallStaticVoidMethod

Tags: c, java-native-interface

The VariantClear works normally if condition is false. But it causes crash if condition is true and the java function is called. Is there something i need to do after the callStaticVoidMethod . Class aa and method bb are both global.

```
VARIANT x;
VariantInit(&x);
if(condition){
  env->CallStaticVoidMethod(aa,bb,cc,dd);
}
VariantClear(&x);
```

Comment: What are `aa, bb, cc, dd`? and where did you get `env` from? and does all this comply with the [JNI Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp4796)?

Comment: aa- my java class, bb - java static void method id, cc and dd - jstring.  i got env from jni call.

Comment: Post the code where you got them. You can't just post the part that is obviously or apparently correct and expect a magical solution. The implication is that one of `aa, bb, cc,` or `env` isn't correct.